# Как использовать escape lodash js?

Tags: javascript, lodash

Необходимо экранировать код с помощью lodash escape, при этом в конечном итоге надо отобразить то что ввел пользователь то есть условно asdasdasd проект написан на js может кто-то знает как это решить ?

Answer (score 0):

> Необходимо экранировать код с помощью lodash escape, при этом в конечном итоге надо отобразить то что ввел пользователь

Подключаем и используем...

```js
document.querySelector('button').addEventListener('click', e => {
  let v = document.querySelector('input').value
  v = _.escape(v)
  console.log(v)
  document.querySelector('p').innerHTML = v
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/lodash@4.17.15/lodash.min.js"></script>

<input value='Пример << название >> строки' />
<button>Тест</button>
<p></p>
```